# Exchange 2010 management shell script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to use a powershell script to check whether the mailbox database status is Mounted on a database. If that is not the case, it must switch to another database.

With the `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus` command I get the necessary output.

And with the `Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase` command I can change the mailbox database.

Now I want to read the output of the `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus`, and use it in the `Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase` command.

Can someone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? Always include your own code, even if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this link: https://practical365.com/exchange-server/powershell-tip-list-active-mailbox-database-copies-exchange-server-database-availability-group/